# htaccess protection asks for every static file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have a htacces protection for my current project:

```
<filesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "secured"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /var/www/html/web/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</filesMatch>
```

The protcetion is working but my static files cames from aws cloudfront and some files are asking for the htaccess credentials too. What can i do to stop this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Files other than `.htm`, `.html`, or `.php`?

Comment: i think this means the opposite.

Comment: Your `.htaccess` rules should match those listed file endings and require authorization. The question is, "is it only those file types that are effected or are other types effected as well?"

Comment: i've changed my htaccess but the error is the same. now i allowed diffetent files and hosts.

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/web/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
Require valid-user
SetEnvIf Host cloudfront.net allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(status.php)$"  allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(appredirect.html)$"  allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy
```

This is the current setting but to allow the host cloudfront.net is not helping.